# Conditional Group in SSRS Tablix or DB View

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I've created a report that is supposed to use a tablix to group data exactly as seen below:

```
Region  |  State  |  Customer  |  CustomerKey | Status
North   | NY      |  Bob       |  111         | VIP
        |         |  Mary      |  112         | VIP
        | MA      |  Bob       |  111         | Regular
        |         |  Tim       |  113         | Regular
East    | MD      |  Greg      |  114         | VIP
        | VA      |  Bob       |  111         | VIP
West    | CA      |  Greg      |  114         | Regular
        |         |  Mary      |  112         | VIP
        |         |  Sean      |  115         | Regular
        | WA      |  Sean      |  115         | VIP
```

This is relatively easy because I am using a view with all the appropriate fields and relations to make grouping in the tablix simple.  I only run into a problem with my VIP Customers.
In the view, customers who have VIP status also have duplicate records of them with Regular status.  For example, the data is stored as follows:

```
Region  |  State  |  Customer  |  CustomerKey | Status
North   | NY      |  Bob       |  111         | VIP
North   | NY      |  Bob       |  111         | Regular
North   | NY      |  Mary      |  112         | VIP
North   | NY      |  Mary      |  112         | Regular
North   | MA      |  Bob       |  111         | Regular
North   | MA      |  Tim       |  113         | Regular
East    | MD      |  Greg      |  114         | VIP
East    | MD      |  Greg      |  114         | Regular
East    | VA      |  Bob       |  111         | VIP
East    | VA      |  Bob       |  111         | Regular
West    | CA      |  Greg      |  114         | Regular
West    | CA      |  Mary      |  112         | VIP
West    | CA      |  Mary      |  112         | Regular
West    | CA      |  Sean      |  115         | Regular
West    | WA      |  Sean      |  115         | VIP
West    | WA      |  Sean      |  115         | Regular
```

My SSRS report is therefore displaying the data as follows:

```
Region  |  State  |  Customer  |  CustomerKey | Status
North   | NY      |  Bob       |  111         | VIP
        |         |            |              | Regular
        |         |  Mary      |  112         | VIP
        |         |            |              | Regular
        | MA      |  Bob       |  111         | Regular
        |         |  Tim       |  113         | Regular
East    | MD      |  Greg      |  114         | VIP
        |         |            |              | Regular
        | VA      |  Bob       |  111         | VIP
        |         |            |              | Regular
West    | CA      |  Greg      |  114         | Regular
        |         |  Mary      |  112         | VIP
        |         |            |              | Regular
        |         |  Sean      |  115         | Regular
        | WA      |  Sean      |  115         | VIP
        |         |            |              | Regular
```

If a user has a Status of VIP, I don't care about their record with their Status of Regular (for that particular Region/State).  Is there anyway I can hide these conditionally?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd look at solving this at a database query level in the first instance.

That said, one way at the report level would be to set up **Groups** based on *Region*, *State* and *Customer*, then in the *Status* column you could have an expression like:

```
=IIf(CountRows("CustomerGroup") = 2, "VIP", "Regular")
```

It's a bit clunky, but should work as it seems each customer can either have one or two rows at the *Region/State* level - if two they must be VIP, and since you've set a a group you're getting distinct values for *Customers* within each *Region/State* combo.

Comment: Thank you Ian, but it appears that the tablix still reflects the 2 rows even if I try to tell it to count the rows of the parent group.  I agree that a change would be more practical to do on the DB end, thinking of adding a CASE column like 'ParentStatus' along the lines of CASE Status WHEN 'Regular' THEN NULL ELSE 'VIP' END...

Comment: What you need to do is set up the three groups without the Details group that's created by default - since there can only be one distinct Region/State/Combination you don't need it. So the row being displayed is actually the customer group header row; when you're doing CountRows it's in the scope of the actual group, not a parent group. But you're right, DB is probably easier... I can think of various ways around it (including the one above) but they're all moot if you can solve this at the lower level.